# Workaround for using tf.matmul with two non-constant inputs

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, tensor2tensor

We are currently trying to convert a transformer model to a tensorflow-lite graph but it seems that the problem is the self-attention mechanism.

We're not able to process the graph. Looking into tf-lite code we narrowed it down to the `tf.matmul` lite-version.

The [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_compatibility) state:

> `tf.matmul` - *as long as the second argument is constant and transposition is not used*

However, this is the case in self-attention:

[image]

(source: [Attention is all you need](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.03762.pdf))

Is there a known workaround for such a situation?

Comment: Why don't you make one constant on the fly, like a prestep on `tf.matmul`? Like `out = tf.constant(V)` and then `tf.matmul(out_softmax, out)`. From what I'vs seen it shouldn't change the result

Comment: @BCJuan How can this be done? `tf.constant` does not allow tensors, does it?

Comment: My bad, you are right. Maybe you are left with your own implementation of `tf.matmul` by using `tf.multiply` and `tf.add`. My apologies

Comment: @BCJuan No problem. You're trying to help :) it's likely that we have to make our own implementation of matmul as it seems